# How to add visual separator between accordion and table in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I want to add visual separator which can be dragged and resized by the used.
I tested this code:

```
public class VerticalSeparator {

    public void initVSeparator(Stage primaryStage, Group root, Scene scene) {

        //Vertical separator
        Separator separator2 = new Separator();
        separator2.setLayoutX(300);
        separator2.setLayoutY(300);

        separator2.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

        root.getChildren().add(separator2);

    }
}
```

But for some reason I don't get anything into the primary stage. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

There is [SplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) control which provides a draggable separator.

```
    SplitPane pane = new SplitPane();
    pane.getItems().addAll(myTable, myAccordion);
```

P.S.: It's hard to tell what's wrong with your code without seeing usage of `VerticalSeparator` class.